# Set RAM split based on HDMI status on boot

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, memory

For the most part, I run my Raspberry Pi headless (which requires very little VRAM). However, I occasionally plug in a monitor (usually after I mess up my SSH configuration).

Is there a way to have the Raspberry Pi allocate less VRAM if HDMI isn't present on boot, and more VRAM when HDMI is connected on boot?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Raspbian and occasionally Arch and Raspbmc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt#CMA_-_Dynamic_Memory_Split):

> The firmware and kernel as of 19. November 2012 supports CMA, which
> means the memory split between ARM and GPU is managed dynamically at
> runtime.

If you enable that, you should not have to do anything -- when you start X, if the GPU needs memory, it can request some from the CPU.  The configuration goes in `/boot/config.txt` and is explained in that elinux link.  I've tried:

```
coherent_pool=6M
smsc95xx.turbo_mode=N
gpu_mem=128
cma_lwm=16
cma_hwm=32
```

This works with the latest stock raspbian kernel (3.10.25), but beware if you have a custom kernel you will need to enable CMA or this will give you grief.  I don't think the first two directives are strictly necessary, YMMV.

Afterward, you should be able to run `vcgencmd commands` and see a list including `cma_config` and `get_mem` (the last one requires a parameter, either `arm` or `gpu`).  If you run `free`, you should have a base mem of ~475 MB, *more* than the ~448 MB without CMA using the default 64 MB of video mem, even though `gpu_mem=128`.

## However...

If all you need the monitor for is special occasions ("usually after I mess up my SSH configuration"), you don't need this, and you don't two configurations either, because you'll get the most RAM (~497 MB) this way:

```
gpu_mem=8
```

No CMA configuration, etc.  This is my preference, and I can plug in an HDMI monitor **and start X**. Most of the memory needed to run a GUI desktop is actually CPU memory.

In short, you don't need much gpu mem at all<sup>1</sup> -- certainly the display will work with much less than the default 64 MB -- and you don't need two configurations.

---

<sup>1. Without having looked into it, I would guess most of time you could never use more than `X resolution` x `Y resolution` x 4 (32-bits/pixel) x 2 (double buffer?) bytes; e.g. for HD 1920 x 1080 x 4 x 2 = 16 MB -- and the use of a double buffer there is a big assumption, so likely only half that. Much larger amounts of GPU memory probably only come into play when openGL-ES, or some other special feature (GPU accelerated video playback) is in use.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Not directly I think, but you could just run a script on bootup that checks the values in `/boot/config.txt`. If they don't match the values needed for the current state of the hdmi, changes the values in config.txt and then performs a reboot.

Easiest way to implement this is to just have two config.txt files. Something like `config-hdmi.txt` and `config-nohdmi.txt`.

Then in pseudo code

```
if( hdmiconnected AND md5(/boot/config.txt)!=md5(/boot/config-hdmi.txt) )
{
  copy /boot/config-hdmi.txt /boot/config.txt
  reboot
}
else if ( !hdmiconnected AND md5(/boot/config.txt)!=md5(/boot/config-nohdmi.txt) )
{
  copy /boot/config-nohdmi.txt /boot/config.txt
  reboot
}
```