# What is the most optimum memory split for streaming pi's as security monitors which you will only ssh into?

Tags: camera, streaming-video, memory, gpu, cpu

I have a few model A's and model B's. I've also read about a few options that allow you to configure an arbitrary split apart from the 16, 32, 64, 128 (and 256 for the B).

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. This is for streaming video over local with a  girthy network speed.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to change the default setting?

Answer (score 2):

I use `gpu_mem=8` and am able to run a GUI, although I mostly use the pi headless and do not have a camera. Note that the split can be managed dynamically while the pi is running, see my [answer to a similar question here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/set-ram-split-based-on-hdmi-status-on-boot/12913#12913).  The logic from the footnote there, vis. resolution, depth, and buffering is an uneducated guess, but it might be applicable to video input processing too.

Answer (score 1):

Just try lowering the GPU-memory values. Once thing start crashing/hanging or display incorrectly, you know you have to go one multiple of 2 above that.