# How to achieve gpu_mem=8?

Tags: performance, memory, gpu, cpu

I see some people claiming (see links) they have a memory splitting of `gpu_mem=8`, but I always thought 16/496 is the minimum split?

- Here is an answer on this very page: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/12913/14614
- Here is a status page I found from someone I found via Google: http://pi.gids.nl:81/piwww/
- In this official forum thread: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=70437

I tried setting it to `gpu_mem=8` on my Pi, it boots just fine, but running

```
vcgencmd get_mem arm
vcgencmd get_mem gpu
```

still gives

```
arm=496M
gpu=16M
```

So on any value below 16 the Pi seems to default to 16. Is there any benefit/drawback when using `gpu_mem=8` or is there a way to really get to 8/504?

Comment: I wonder if its just a kernel restriction? You need some memory for HDMI frame buffers. Can you confirm these guys got it set to 8mb? or maybe it was just a typo or misunderstanding. Maybe you can turn HDMI off and set 0/512mb. That would be nice for me, I never use HDMI.

Comment: is this (504/496=1.016) 1.6% improvement really worth thinking about?

Comment: @lenik No for real problems, but yes for learning and understanding details.

Comment: @ppumkin I can't confirm that their devices really run on 8/504, they only posted their config and I wondered why they set it to 8 if 16 is the minimum.

Comment: Perhaps gpu_mem=8 is the minimum for 256mb RAM, while gpu_mem=16 is the minimum for 512mb RAM. When you only have 256mb of RAM, 8mb is a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum amount of RAM allocated to the GPU has a recommended lower limit of 16MB. This is due to the build of the Raspberry Pi itself.